# How to make a Ul list item unselectable

Tags: javascript, css

I have following ul. I want to make any particular list item unselectable.

```
<ul>
  <li>ABC</li>
  <li>PQR</li>
  <li>XYZ</li>
</ul>
```

How can I do this? I tried setting following css class, but did not help

```
.unselectable {
 -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by unselectable?

Comment: This might be silly, or obvious, but could you also just show us how you're setting up your HTML?

Comment: I want to do this using javascript. Make one of the list item as unselectable or disable it

Comment: Check this link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting?rq=1`

Answer (score 5):

It does work, but I think the problem you might be having is in the way you are setting up your HTML.

Ensure that the `<li>` elements you want to not be selectable have the `unselectable` class, as per this example:

```
<li class="unselectable">unselectable</li>
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/TtLQa/1/

Also, please refer to [this link](http://caniuse.com/user-select-none) for browser support information with regards to `user-select:none`.

---

**Edit:**

I just saw your comment, you want to do this via javascript.

Using jQuery, you can easily add or remove a class as you wish:

```
$(element).addClass("unselectable");
$(element).removeClass("unselectable");

//removes it if it is there, or adds it if it is not
$(element).toggleClass("unselectable");
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/TtLQa/4/